# UICollectionView custom cell did not reload

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have download sample project of UICollectionVIew. I have created custom cell in code and in that cell I am adding UI elements(image, button etc). The problem is when I dequeue the cell I did not get the reusable cell. Here is the link of the code.

http://speedy.sh/kq3mr/code.zip

Kindly Guide me where I am doing wrong

Comment: As you can see in demo images are not showing in few cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

self.imageView.frame = frame;

The above line of code (self.imageView.frame = frame) is causing the issue. It should be

self.imageView.frame = self.bounds

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier will reuse cell just if already created cell is available. Otherwise dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier will create and return new cell.